# Force type constraint using `typedef`

Tags: c++

For example I have to declarations:

```
typedef int Type1;
typedef int Type2;
```

Can I force the compiler to treat `Type1` and `Type2` as different type? For example when I do this:

```
Type1 t1 = 3;
Type2 t2 = t1;
```

Can I make the second assignment invalid due to different type?